# How to convert a function that returns an observable to an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following code which works fine. What I want is to convert the getSaveObs function to an arrow function so I can use it inside the save function.

```
private save(property: IProperty): void {
  // I want the getSaveObs logic to be moved here instead of a separate function
  this.getSaveObs(property)
   .subscribe(savedProperty => {
    this.property = savedProperty;
    this.propertyStorageService.storeProperty(this.property);
    this.propertyDetailsForm.get('id').setValue(this.property.id);
    // if new property, move to step 2
    if (!savedProperty.id) {
      console.log('New property, moving to step 2');
      if (this.clientId) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/clients/' + this.clientId + '/properties/' + this.property.id + '/' + '2');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/properties', this.property.id, '2']);
      }
    }
  }, error => (console.error('Error adding/updating a property: ', error)));
}


private getSaveObs(property: IProperty): Observable<IProperty> {
  if (property.id) {
    if (this.clientId) {
        return this.clientPropertiesService.updateProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId,                
           this.clientId, property);
    } else {
        return this.profileService.updateProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, property);
    }
  } else {
    // New property observable
    if (this.clientId) {
        return this.clientPropertiesService.createProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, 
           this.clientId, property);
    } else {
      return this.profileService.createProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, property);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is one of the methods called that returns Observable

```
createUserProperty(property: IProperty, userDocument: 
    AngularFirestoreCollection): EntityResponseType {
    delete property.id;
    property.modifiedTs = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
    property.createdTs = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();

    return from(userDocument.add(property))
      .pipe(
         map(res => {
         return {...property, id: res.id};
      })
    );
 }
```

Comment: Observables allow for your code to listen to the `getSaveObs` any time it emits. Do you want to retain that feature or do you just need to run the function and wait for the result?

Comment: I am using firebase to store the data and the create/update methods convert the firebase promise to observable using from(....). I am not sure if this is the best approach though. I updated the description to show one of the methods that return 
 an observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you believe that an arrow function can be used in `save(property: IProperty): void` and a regular function cannot? What are you trying to do?

---

Regardless any function can be turned into an arrow function like this

```js
function someName(arg: ArgType): ReturnType {
  /*...function body...*/
}
```

becomes

```js
const someName = (arg: ArgType): ReturnType => {
  /*...function body...*/
}
```

SO in your case, that's:

```js
const getSaveObs = (property: IProperty): Observable<IProperty> => {
  if (property.id) {
    if (this.clientId) {
        return this.clientPropertiesService.updateProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId,                
           this.clientId, property);
    } else {
        return this.profileService.updateProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, property);
    }
  } else {
    // New property observable
    if (this.clientId) {
        return this.clientPropertiesService.createProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, 
           this.clientId, property);
    } else {
      return this.profileService.createProperty(this.accountService.userIdentity.userId, property);
    }
  }
}
```